# Is it possible to have HTML emails in osTicket?

Tags: email

I have an e-mail template that I use to send out account emails and I'd like to use the same HTML email template via osTicket.. is this possible?

Comment: Hi, did you ever get HTML into the outgoing emails in osticket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be out of luck.  Take a look at [this forum post](http://osticket.com/forums/showthread.php?t=4352) from osTicket.  HTML is stripped from the email before sending.

Answer (score 3):

Modifications in **class.ticket.php**

1. Add this **new function**

   function getHtmlEmailTemplate(){
            return $this->config['html_email_template'];
       }
2. add this line to $sql var at UpdatePref() function...

   ',spoof_default_smtp='.db_input(($var['default_smtp_id'] && isset($var['spoof_default_smtp']))?1:0).

Modifications in **class.email.php**

1. Replace your Send() function by this one:

> ```
> function send($to,$subject,$message,$attachment=null) {
>         global $cfg;
>
>         //Get SMTP info IF enabled!
>         $smtp=array();
>         if($this->isSMTPEnabled() && ($info=$this->getSMTPInfo())){ 
>             $smtp=$info;
>         }elseif($cfg && ($email=$cfg->getDefaultSMTPEmail()) && $email->isSMTPEnabled()){ //What about global SMTP setting?
>             if($cfg->allowSMTPSpoofing() && ($info=$email->getSMTPInfo())){ 
>                 $smtp=$info;
>             }elseif($email->getId()!=$this->getId()){
>                 return $email->send($to,$subject,$message,$attachment);
>             }
>         }
>
>         //Get the goodies
>         require_once ('Mail.php'); // PEAR Mail package
>         require_once ('Mail/mime.php'); // PEAR Mail_Mime packge
>
>         //do some cleanup
>         $eol="\n";
>         $to=preg_replace("/(\r\n|\r|\n)/s",'', trim($to));
>         $subject=stripslashes(preg_replace("/(\r\n|\r|\n)/s",'', trim($subject)));
>         $body = stripslashes(preg_replace("/(\r\n|\r)/s", "\n", trim($message)));
>         $htmlbody = str_replace('%message', str_replace("\n", '<br />', $body), $cfg->getHtmlEmailTemplate());
>         $fromname=$this->getName();
>         $from =sprintf('"%s"<%s>',($fromname?$fromname:$this->getEmail()),$this->getEmail());
>         $headers = array ('From' => $from,
>                           'To' => $to,
>                           'Subject' => $subject,
>                           'Date'=>date('D, d M Y H:i:s O'),
>                           'Message-ID' =>'<'.Misc::randCode(6).''.time().'-'.$this->getEmail().'>',
>                           'X-Mailer' =>'osTicket v 1.6',
>                           'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset="UTF-8"'
>                           );
>         $mime = new Mail_mime();
>         $mime->setTXTBody($body);
>         if (strpos($cfg->getHtmlEmailTemplate(), '%message') !== false) 
>           $mime->setHTMLBody($htmlbody);
>         //attachment TODO: allow multiple attachments - $attachment should be mixed parts.
>         if($attachment && $attachment['file'] && is_readable($attachment['file'])) { 
>             $mime->addAttachment($attachment['file'],$attachment['type'],$attachment['name']);
>         }
>         $options=array('head_encoding' => 'quoted-printable',
>                        'text_encoding' => 'quoted-printable',
>                        'html_encoding' => 'base64',
>                        'html_charset'  => 'utf-8',
>                        'text_charset'  => 'utf-8');
>         //encode the body
>         $body = $mime->get($options);
>         //encode the headers.
>         $headers = $mime->headers($headers);
>         if($smtp){ //Send via SMTP
>             $mail = mail::factory('smtp',
>                     array ('host' => $smtp['host'],
>                            'port' => $smtp['port'],
>                            'auth' => $smtp['auth']?true:false,
>                            'username' => $smtp['username'],
>                            'password' => $smtp['password'],
>                            'timeout'  =>20,
>                            'debug' => false,
>                            ));
>             $result = $mail->send($to, $headers, $body);
>             if(!PEAR::isError($result))
>                 return true;
>
>             $alert=sprintf("Unable to email via %s:%d [%s]\n\n%s\n",$smtp['host'],$smtp['port'],$smtp['username'],$result->getMessage());
>             Sys::log(LOG_ALERT,'SMTP Error',$alert,false);
>             //print_r($result);
>         }
>
>         //No SMTP or it failed....use php's native mail function.
>         $mail = mail::factory('mail');
>         return PEAR::isError($mail->send($to, $headers, $body))?false:true;
>
>     }
> ```

2.- Replace your sendmail() function by this one:

```
function sendmail($to,$subject,$message,$from) {

        require_once ('Mail.php'); // PEAR Mail package
        require_once ('Mail/mime.php'); // PEAR Mail_Mime packge

        $eol="\n";
        $to=preg_replace("/(\r\n|\r|\n)/s",'', trim($to));
        $subject=stripslashes(preg_replace("/(\r\n|\r|\n)/s",'', trim($subject)));
        $body = stripslashes(preg_replace("/(\r\n|\r)/s", "\n", trim($message)));
        $htmlbody = str_replace('%message', str_replace("\n", '<br />', $body), $cfg->getHtmlEmailTemplate()); 
        $headers = array ('From' =>$from,
                          'To' => $to,
                          'Subject' => $subject,
                          'Message-ID' =>'<'.Misc::randCode(10).''.time().'@osTicket>',
                          'X-Mailer' =>'osTicket v 1.6',
                          'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset="UTF-8"'
                          );
        $mime = new Mail_mime();
        $mime->setTXTBody($body);
        if (strpos($cfg->getHtmlEmailTemplate(), '%message') !== false) 
          $mime->setHTMLBody($htmlbody);
        $options=array('head_encoding' => 'quoted-printable',
                       'text_encoding' => 'quoted-printable',
                       'html_encoding' => 'base64',
                       'html_charset'  => 'utf-8',
                       'text_charset'  => 'utf-8');
        //encode the body
        $body = $mime->get($options);
        //headers
        $headers = $mime->headers($headers);
        $mail = mail::factory('mail');
        return PEAR::isError($mail->send($to, $headers, $body))?false:true;
    }
```

Modifications in **preference.inc.php**

1.- Add this HTML code where you want inside the table

```
<tr><th>HTML Email Template:</th>
          <td><textarea rows="15" name="html_email_template" style="width:600px;"><?=$config['html_email_template']?></textarea><br><i>Will be used for all outgoing emails.<br />Insert %message where you want the message text to be replaced in the template.</i></td>
        </tr>
```

Finally you have got a TextArea at Preferences/Settings page which allow you to write your own HTML code for the template. Just type %message where you want to place the message into the template  :)